# the variation between treatments is less than the variation between replicates in RNA-seq data

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2, edger, pca, limma

I have a set of `RNA-seq` samples from targeting different proteins in a complex with `siRNAs`. However, the `PCA` plot shows that **the distance between the two replicates of each treatment is more than the distance between the treatments**. So, there is **no clear border between treatments** to cluster them separately.

If I go through my usual RNA-seq data analysis pipeline using `EdgeR` normalization and `Limma/Voom` DEG analysis, I get a lot of DEGs. However, when I try to visualize them using a heatmap, the replicates do not cluster together, as expected.

What should I do in this situation? I mean should I trust the DEGs, or try to still extract co-expressed gene modules from this data?

my code for normalization:

```
myDGEList <- DGEList(Txi_gene$counts)
log2.cpm <- cpm(myDGEList, log=TRUE)

cpm <- cpm(myDGEList)

# prepare your grouping matrix
group <- factor(targets$group)
design <- model.matrix(~group)

# filtering
keepers <- filterByExpr(cpm, design)
myDGEList.filtered <- myDGEList[keepers,]
log2.cpm.filtered <- cpm(myDGEList.filtered, log=TRUE)

myDGEList.filtered.norm <- calcNormFactors(myDGEList.filtered, method = "TMM")
log2.cpm.filtered.norm <- cpm(myDGEList.filtered.norm, log=TRUE)
```

my code for PCA plot:

```
pca.res <- prcomp(t(log2.cpm.filtered.norm), scale.=F, retx=T)
pc.var <- pca.res$sdev^2
pc.per <- round(pc.var/sum(pc.var)*100, 1) 
pca.res.df <- as_tibble(pca.res$x)

# PC1 vs PC2
pca.plot <- ggplot(pca.res.df) +
  aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, label=sampleLabels, color = group, shape = batch) +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  xlab(paste0("PC1 (",pc.per[1],"%",")")) + 
  ylab(paste0("PC2 (",pc.per[2],"%",")")) +
  labs(title="PCA plot",
       caption=paste0("produced on ", Sys.time())) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw()

ggplotly(pca.plot)
```

the PCA plot figure. The legend is cropped out for privacy reasons. Colors represent replicates. Shapes represent batch effect which was has been fixed using `combat_seq` on raw-data.
[image: PCA plot]

Comment: Can you show the pca plot you're describing?

Comment: Please include plots and all relevant code. It is difficult to argue only on words in this context.

Comment: Do you have a plot before Combat batch correction? It may be easier to add the batch information to the edgeR model formula and not correct in in the counts.

Comment: @PPK I do have a plot but my replicates are in different batches, so the PC1 positive side is replicate 1 (batch1) of each treatment and PC1 negative side is replicate 2 (batch2) of each treatment in not batch corrected PCA plot. At first, I used EdgeR model for batch effect and just used combat for visualization but I comapred them and the reults were almost identical, so I used combat-seq on my raw data before any normalization. Do you still think I should add a PCA without batch correction to the question?

Comment: Can you show the PCAplot without correction, I think your plot above looks weird. Also when you mentioned you found DEGs, which comparison did you find it for? I see many groups here. For the comparion you are interested in, make a histogram of the p-values and see whether there is an enrichment in low p-values

Comment: The answer to your question is, they should be ok, unless you are underestimating the variance by not including relevant covariates. Still I think you have to interpret the data to see whether it makes sense. It would help a lot if you make some of these diagnostic plots, otherwise it is pretty much guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If you got DEGs with statistically significant p-values after multiple testing following a valid pipeline, **I'd believe that**, even if looking at the first few PCs doesn't look promising.